# Installing mysql2 0.3.13

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble finding good instructions on how to install gem mysql2-0.3.13 and have it up and running for a ruby on rails application. Could anyone please break down this process?  When I try to install the gem, I get this error:
I m using rails 3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3 and mac OSX

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........  
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..  
/Users/sumitkalra1984/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:284: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Using rake (10.1.0)   
Using i18n (0.6.5)   
Using minitest (4.7.5)   
Using multi_json (1.7.9)   
Using atomic (1.1.13)   
Using thread_safe (0.1.2)   
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)   
Using activesupport (4.0.0)   
Using builder (3.1.4)   
Using erubis (2.7.0)   
Using rack (1.5.2)   
Using rack-test (0.6.2)   
Using actionpack (4.0.0)   
Using mime-types (1.24)   
Using polyglot (0.3.3)   
Using treetop (1.4.15)   
Using mail (2.5.4)   
Using actionmailer (4.0.0)   
Using activemodel (4.0.0)   
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)   
Using arel (4.0.0)   
Using activerecord (4.0.0)   
Using thor (0.18.1)   
Using railties (4.0.0)   
Using activerecord-session_store (0.0.1)   
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1)   
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)   
Using execjs (2.0.0)   
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)   
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)   
Using daemons (1.1.9)   
Using orm_adapter (0.4.0)   
Using warden (1.2.3)   
Using devise (3.0.3)   
Using eventmachine (1.0.3)   
Using multipart-post (1.2.0)   
Using faraday (0.8.8)   
Using hashie (2.0.5)   
Using hike (1.2.3)   
Using httpauth (0.2.0)   
Using jbuilder (1.5.0)   
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)   
Using json (1.8.0)   
Using jwt (0.1.8)   
Using libv8 (3.16.14.3)   
Installing mysql2 (0.3.13)   
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/sumitkalra1984/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/MIT-LICENSE  
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.13), and Bundler cannot continue.  
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: just to make sure: have you got MySql installed and properly working on your machine?

Answer (score 8):

If you have facing permission problem then install the gems as a root user
like

```
sudo bundle install
```

please check you have mysql installed properly
and for `Mysql2 gem` before installing the gem type

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev libmysql-ruby
```

I am not a mac user but It work's  in ubuntu. Hope this could help you.

Comment: sorry still things doesn't work, i've used both the commands but still can't get fruitful result. for second command it is giving an error apt-get: command not found. please help.

Comment: apt-get command may not work in mac. Please check the equivalent code for mac.To use mysql2 gem you need those libraries.

Comment: I've a doubt sabyasachi this command is for installing mysql server or mysql2 gem? please clearify?

Comment: this command in installing mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev libmysql-ruby all the 3 things

Comment: I've ununstalled mysql then reinstalled it still things are not working bundle install is giving same error as before, I am still unable to find the reason why it is giving an error EACCESS: Permission Denied.

Comment: @Ishan i am not sure the permission problem. you can check the permission of application folder or make a bundle install as a root user.

Comment: Finally gem is installed thnx @sabyasachi for ur kind help.

Comment: sorry sabyasachi gem was installed but it was not mysql2 0.3.13 , an older version of gem is installed. For that gem which i want to install it is still showing the same error.

Comment: it worked nicely for the first time but when i close nd restart the server it started again to show the same error then i allows the permission of read and write on mysql2-0.3.13 folder in MIT-LICENSE file using terminal and after that i run the command bundle install and now it is showing error : Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - /Users/sumitkalra1984/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/MIT-LICENSE
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.13), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Do not use sudo for bundler

Comment: @ajbraus yes generally you don't need sudo but if you have permission issue in that case you have to use sudo to be a root user.

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the same problem. To fix this problem, open a command prompt. go to your application folder. And type: gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.11  this version is working great. this is for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are in my same situation. I've solved checking out if in my RVM there was a directory for mysql gem (probably generated from previous bundle commands). I've removed the folder and then i've run again `bundle install`.